# modem or mobile broadband showing differect ip address

Tags: ip

my modem or mobile broadband is perfectly connects with internet  but i unable to install anything via terminal  in connection information it shows the IP address 115.243.74.182 but in termainal it shows this connecting to 192.168.100.3 whic is the IP address of wifi provided by college how can i fix it ?? please help me..

Comment: See more detailas about [Internal and External IP address.](http://techmans.blogspot.com/2014/05/what-is-internal-and-external-ip.html)

Answer (score 0):

192.168.100.3 is your internal IP from the network that you connect to.

Your external IP is provided by your ISP. You can find it by going [here](http://www.whatismyip.com/), for example.

Regarding being unable to install anything, are there proxies that you need to set up?